# Why are 2 uri's are passed to the trigger when working with temporal documents?

Tags: triggers, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

We use triggers to trigger a DHF Harmonize flow once a raw input document arrives. The harmonize flow runs fine and a harmonized entity is created, however we also have errors in the log for a failed harmonize.

The input documents are unitemporal and saved with the “temporal:statement-set-document-version-uri” function so the uri of the document is persisted once a new version arrives.
Sample of the error message: “error in a plugin (PLUGIN-ERROR): XDMP-ASerr:XPTY00041.0-mlInvalid coercionXDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $value as xs:string -- Invalid coercion: () as xs:stringfalse$value…”

It appears that if the input document is new, both the document uri and the temporal uri-collection of the document are passed to the trigger. The document-uri is running the harmonize flow, but the temporal uri-collection is causing the error in the logs.
When the input document is a new version of an existing temporal document only the document-uri is passed to the trigger and all works fine.
I would expect that in any case, only the document-uri is passed to the trigger. Is this a bug, or is this behavior by design?

Comment: Which version of MarkLogic, and are you using pre- or post-commit triggers?

Comment: We use marklogic 9.0-5 and post-commit triggers.